# ggplot2: : Equivalent of axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Consider the following plot:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-3, +3)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) 4*x^(1/2)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) x^2)
```

[image: parabola]

I would like to add an axis to the current plot. With the standard `graphics` package, one uses `axis()`

Is it possible to reproduce `axis()`  in ggplot2?

Comment: You mean centered as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753101/center-x-and-y-axis-with-ggplot2) ?

Comment: I think you could start a bounty

Comment: I think the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753101/center-x-and-y-axis-with-ggplot2 is not satisfacory, it should not be labeled as duplicated

Comment: @Marco The question is still a dupe, even if the previous one hasn't been answered satisfactorily (yet).

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134299/r-how-can-i-plot-such-ggplot2 is closer to what he has in mind, except it is done in base graphics.  @Marco: is it critical that it has to be done in ggplot2?  if so, you want to suppress the axes and then draw ablines and labeling will be tedious.  I would suggest to look at the answer by **jbaums** (in my link) and try it in base graphics.

Comment: @3lectrologos: now it is different. So if reopened I can open the bounty.